# Asp.Net token authentication redirect to login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, access-token

Aiming to use best and modern practices I decied to implement token authentication in my web application and I was able to make it to work but the fact is I'm not being able to redirect to login page on unauthorized access, instead it throws a **401.0 blank page with error**.

I was googling and found this next piece of code to be put on Configure method on **Startup.cs** to redirect depending of Http status error code but Visual Studio is complaining with **IAppBuilder does not contain a definition for UseStatusCodePages.**

First of all I'd like to know which specific package should I add so method UseStatusCodePages is found but I'd also like to know if this is the best approach to redirect to login page on unauthorized access using token authentication or if not what do you suggest.

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{            
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    var path = request.Path.Value ?? "";

    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && path.StartsWith("/api", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
    }
});
```

This is my ConfigureOAuth method:

```
public static void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,                
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new ADAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
```

Another option is to use a custom authorize class like so:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Login" }));
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Employee" }));
        }
    }
}
```

And with this second approach replacing [Authorize] with [CustomAuthorize] is working fine but the fact is I wouldn't like to be in the need to use a CustomAuthorize instead of the default one so what do you think? Is this second one a good approach? Should I keep the first? What about UseStatusCodePages not being found? In the end, is it a good idea to use token auth on an app which most likely won't use web api?

FYI, I'm using MVC with Asp.Net Framework 4.6.1

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the code for token authentication  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183150/Securing-ASP-NET-Web-API-using-Custom-Token-Based